# Interlocked.Increment on dictionary value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-services

I'm trying to use a Dictionary to record the current request count per API path on a web service, and to increase and decrease the current count I thought a good way would be using `Interlocked.Increment()` because it increases the count and reads the count at the same time.

However the following code gave an error saying **ref argument is not classified as a variable**, I'm guessing it's because `dict[key]` is not a variable?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("a", 1);
int i = Interlocked.Increment(ref dict["a"]);
```

I knew `Interlocked.Increment()` cannot be applied to properties but wouldn't have thought accessing dictionary via the key would have the same problems.

What's the best way to go about this?

**Edit: Here're some more details about this.**

I'm trying to write some code to throttle the number of API calls on each API path of the web service, so I have two dictionaries, the policy dictionary which specify how many concurrent callers are allowed on each API Path and a second counter Dictionary to record how many callers currently are active on each API Path.

Before the web service executes any incoming request, it will check the above two dictionaries to decide whether the request should continue or simply return a HTTP 429 (Too Many Requests) response straight away.

Here is an extract of the code, it firstly checks if there's a matching policy and then if so it then checks whether the max allowed requests are breached.

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.ToString();
    var policy = _policies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndpointPath == url);

    if (policy != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentRequests[policy]) > policy.MaxConcurrentConnection)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 429;
                var message = string.Format(
                    "Max API concurrent calls quota exceeded, please try again later. Maximum admitted: {0}",
                    policy.MaxConcurrentConnection);
                context.Response.Write(message);
                context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Too Many Requests";
            }
            else
            {
                await Next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _currentRequests[policy]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Even if this code worked, it wouldn't guarantee thread-safe modification of the stored value. It would only guarantee thread safety of the *returned copy*. Perhaps you are looking for ConcurrentDictionary or one of the Immutable classes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , why wouldn't this guarantee thread-safe modification of the value in the dictionary..I was hoping Interlocked.Increment (ref something) will ensure different thread can modify and read the value of something safely. I'll edit the question to give more details. Thanks.

Comment: Because `int` is a *value type* which means upon assignment you get a copy, *not* a reference to the stored object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah.so you mean using 'ref dict["a"]' I'm actually passing the reference to a copy of the value in dict["a"] and even if Interlock.Increment works I'm not actually increasing the value in dict["a"]?. I edited the question to give a bit more details.

Comment: try to use `lock` statement instead of Interlocked

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary  Thanks...I'll give that a try.. just thought using Interlocked.Increment makes code shorter and easier to read and I didn't really understand why it wound't work on a dictionary value..

Comment: If that's the only reason you were using `Interlocked`, then use a `lock` for sure. It's really no harder to read, and also a lot more people know about `lock` than know about `Interlocked`. I did start to formulate a solution to your issue that would allow you to use Interlocked, but unless you're having performance issues then I'd stick with lock. The way to use Interlocked will make your code much harder to understand, although it is possible. Let me know if you still want me to write it up for you.

Comment: @RichardIrons, thanks for the kind offering..  performance is not a big concern in my case so I guess if I'll stick with lock .. however I would really appreciate if you can outline your solution just in a few words (if possible), it doesn't have to some complete code just you thought will be sufficient so I can get a rough idea about how to approach that. thanks again.

Comment: OK just briefly. A dictionary is done through property gets, so you can't do interlocked stuff on its values. However, you can do Interlocked operations on array cells - they are fixed memory locations accessed directly. So you would set up a big array, and then your dictionary, rather than returning the count itself, would return an index into that array, and then the count would be stored in the array. Then you could do an Interlocked operation on the array cell. Of course, you'd wrap this up in a class so that using the class looked the same as using a dictionary.

Comment: Another way you could do it is each item in the dictionary would be a "Count" object. You call methods on those objects to increment, decrement, and get the current value. Internally, those objects are using Interlocked to increment and decrement their private `int`, accessed in a read-only way using a property accessor.

Comment: @RichardIrons thanks mate, these are very good ideas. If you can repost them below I'll mark them as the answer.

Comment: Sure, gimme a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main reason to use `Interlocked` is performance. If you're not having performance issues then your code will be understandable to more people, and easier to write and read, if you simply use a `lock`.

If you absolutely *must* use `Interlocked`, then you can't do it with a dictionary in the way you've tried to. `Interlocked` operations are atomic, often at the CPU level, and they require a fixed location in memory on which to operate. The property accessors on a dictionary don't provide this.

If you still wanted to use dictionaries, there are two methods that spring to mind:

#### Store your counts in an array

You'd store your count values in an array. Each cell is fixed in memory and can therefore be used by `Interlocked`. You dictionary, rather than storing the count, would store the index in this array at which the count was stored. Of course, you would write this all into a class such that these implementation details where hidden.

#### Store "count objects" in the dictionary

Each item in the dictionary would be an instance of a class that holds the count. Internally to the class, there would be a `private int` that could be used by `Interlocked`. Your class would provide `Increment` and `Decrement` methods, and a read-only `Count` property, to allow this to be used in a similar way.

**edit**

#### Use A Semaphore

Actually, one other thing you could look into is using a `Semaphore`. They're pretty much [designed for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx). By having each cell in the Dictionary be a `Semaphore` rather than a count, you can achieve a very similar thing in a threadsafe way. You would do `dictionary[key].WaitOne(0)`, which would return true if it succeeded, and false if not. If it *did* return true, then that Semaphore's count has already been incremented and you just call `Dictionary[hey].Release()` again later.

Answer (score 7):

Store a mutable heap object in the dictionary:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<..., StrongBox<int>> dict = ...;
Interlocked.Increment(ref dict[...].Value);
```

`StrongBox.Value` is a mutable field.

Comment: @user8549339 please be more specific than just "error". I changed the answer to use ConcurrentDictionary so that you can add to it safely. This was indeed a bug.

Comment: It was actually something to do with my own code. It does indeed work :) ConcurrentDictionary was not required on my end though for my current setup.

Answer (score 7):

It is actually much easier. specially if you are not sure if the key is created or not.

The below, will increment the value by one if it exists and create it with a default value of 1 if it doesn't. Concurrents namespace contains almost everything you will ever need to build threadsafe objects. I don't generally like the use of locks as it serializes access to the object (Why are we doing multi-threading if we will do it in serial?)

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dataStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

public int Increment(string key)
{
    return dataStore.AddOrUpdate(key, 1, (k, v) => Interlocked.Increment(ref v));
}
```

Comment: Using `Interlocked.Increment` inside the `updateValueFactory` delegate is redundant. `(k, v) => v + 1` would work just fine. The `v` variable is local, and cannot be accessed by other threads concurrently. The [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate) method fakes atomicity by discarding the return value and re-invoking the delegate in case another thread was faster at updating a specific key.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, True, there is a lock in the concurrent dictionary implementation.

Comment: This is misleading for a lot of people that do not understand the ConcurrentDictionary very well, therefore I would suggest to remove it.

Comment: This is need since there is no lock on updateValueFactory.  Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-5.0  `However, the updateValueFactory delegate is called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock`